# Simple FDA question

Tags: api, healthcare-finder-api, barcodes

I'm trying to request data on UDI...

https://api.fda.gov/device/udi.json?api_key=xxxxxxxx&search=identifiers.id:EFOR74982201001

Is the identifiers.id field the UDI? Each time I input my own UDI, the response is 'Not found'. Example UDI: 827002041370